# How can I put single quotes in a string?

Tags: matlab

I'm facing a problem with string in MATLAB the default string is `C:\Users\Root\Downloads\Path`. I want to make this string with single quotes inside it like this `'C:\Users\Root\Downloads\Path\'`. I try many times to escape the string with backslash like other programming languages but MATLAB didn't doing this i don't know how to fix this problem.

Code:

```
clear all
clc
s='C:\Users\Root\Downloads\Path';
str=fprintf('%s',s);
```

Comment: @StewieGriffin it save this string in workspace as a characters but i want to save these characters as a single string

Comment: See my answer. The string is saved as `s`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use two quotes instead of one:

```
s='''C:\Users\Root\Downloads\Path''';    
str=fprintf('%s',s)
'C:\Users\Root\Downloads\Path'
str =    
    30
```

Note that `str` will be the number `30`, since `fprintf` returns the number of characters it prints, not the string itself! If you just want the string, then the first line is enough.

```
disp(s)
'C:\Users\Root\Downloads\Path'
```

Note that there is no data type "String" in MATLAB. You have an [array of characters](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html).