# Keeping values of cell arrays when exporting to Excel

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, export-to-excel

I have a cell array. Some of the elements in this cell array contains zeros as the first character and the whole element is only numbers (double) as well. When exporting these to Excel (which I prefer), the zeros are deleted and converting it to a number.

Let's take an example to illustrate my problem. I have a cell array with 10 elements:

```
NodeID = {'0000006';
          '0000011';
          '000011R';
          '000016R';
          '000021R';
          'B276_2';
          'EB 7.55';
          'EB2521';
          'EllebaekOPlB1';
          'EllebaekOplB10'};
```

The first two elements contains zeros until the number 6 and 11, respectively. Unlike the third element and so forth, where letters are involved. So when exporting `NodeID` to Excel, it returns this in a column (I use `writetable` command by the way):

```
6
11
000011R
000016R
000021R
B276_2
EB 7.55'
EB2521
EllebaekOPlB1
EllebaekOplB10
```

Notice the removal of zeros for the first two elements. Now I know that in Excel, it will keep all the content with the addition of a quote symbol `'` in front of the cell, eg. `'0000006` for the first element.

I have searched in many places to find a solution to this. But is there a good way to avoid this from happening? Either by somehow adding an extra `´` or some other magical trick which I have not seen?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a table or a cell array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative (if your values are in a cell, as you say they are):

```
filename = 'NodeID.xlsx';
NodeID2 = cellfun(@(C) ['''',C], NodeID,'UniformOutput', false)
xlswrite(filename, NodeID2)
```

This gives you:

```
NodeID2 =     
    ''0000006'
    ''0000011'
    ''000011R'
    ''000016R'
    ''000021R'
    ''B276_2'
    ''EB 7.55'
    ''EB2521'
    ''EllebaekOPlB1'
    ''EllebaekOplB10'
```

And an Excel file looking like this:

[image]

The `cellfun` line is equivalent to:

```
for ii = 1:numel(NodeID)
   NodeID2{ii,1} = ['''', NodeID{ii}];
end
```

The part `['''', NodeID{ii}]` inserts a single quotation mark in front for the string. [Relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207912/2338750).

Comment: Works perfectly. But I realized that you can't use my prefered `writetable` to do it. Then it will put two `''` in the cell. So `xlswrite` as you suggest works like a charm :) Thank you!